# Webpack not injecting css to cshtml

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to add use `webpack` and it will not add the CSS to `cshtml` file.

webpack.common.config

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    target: 'web',
    entry: ['./Client/src/app.js', './Client/src/app.scss'],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/wwwroot/dist/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'webpack-import-glob-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: 'webpack-import-glob-loader'
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: "body",
            filename: "../../Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml",
            template: "./Views/Shared/_LoginLayout_Template.cshtml"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: "body",
            filename: "../../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml",
            template: "./Views/Shared/_Layout_Template.cshtml"
        }),
    ]
};
module.exports = config;
```

Generated _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - PipelineSolutions</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg" href="~/pipelines_managment.svg" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7466cd573b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/fonts/roboto/roboto.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Styles", false)
</head>
<body>

    <partial name="_Sidebar" model="@ViewData["SidebarItems"]" />

    <div id="main-content">
        <partial name="_Navbar" />
        <div id="loading">
            <img id="loading-image" src="~/rotating_icon.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
        <div id="main-container" class="container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div id="user-notifications"></div>
    </div>
    
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
<script defer src="~/dist/main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

As you can see it does add the bundle file which is great. but it doesn't apply the CSS.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work. using

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
//and adding this plugin
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        insert:'head'
    })
```

I hope this helps others in the same spot.